# Clever Impersonator copying Liliana Heretical Healer

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm copying my opponent's non-transformed [Liliana, Heretical Healer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liliana%2C%20Heretical%20Healer) with [Clever Impersonator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clever%20Impersonator). Then one of my other creatures dies. Does my Clever Impersonator come back as Liliana non-transformed again or does it come back as Clever Impersonator with a possible new choice? If it comes back as Liliana do I get a zombie? It says "If you do, put a 2/2..." is it saying if I do return her, or if I do return her transformed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You will get the 2/2 Zombie token and a fresh *Clever Impersonator*.**

The copied Liliana's ability triggers on the other creature's death, the copied Liliana gets exiled and returns to the battlefield. However, the Impersonator only copied the front side of Liliana, the Impersonator itself can not and will not be transformed:

> 701.25a Only permanents represented by double-faced cards can transform. (See rule 711, “Double-Faced Cards.”) If a spell or ability instructs a player to transform any permanent that isn’t represented by a double-faced card, nothing happens.

In this case, the "If you do..." part of Liliana's ability is sufficiently satisfied as long as the card is exiled due to the effect, so a 2/2 zombie will be created. (see [this post](http://magicjudge.tumblr.com/post/125330140254/re-the-dfc-walkers-and-copy-effects-how-does))

Upon leaving the battlefield, the Impersonator also forgot all memory of its previous existence:

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are seven exceptions to this rule:

The exceptions don't apply here. You exile the Liliana, but return the Impersonator. Therefore, after the exile it enters the battlefield as a fresh Impersonator, ready to copy another permanent.

Comment: Do the impersonator-cloned Liliana put a zombie token on the battlefield when it happens ? Just trying to clarify.

Comment: @Autar No, you get the zombie token only when you return the transformed Liliana ("If you do,...").

Comment: @Hackworth I'm pretty sure the 'If you do...' refers to exiling her, so you would get the token.

Comment: http://magicjudge.tumblr.com/post/125330140254/re-the-dfc-walkers-and-copy-effects-how-does

Comment: You should probably add that to the answer, since it's part of the question.

Comment: @diego Is there a rule that explains why this is the case? From the wording on the card it seems completely ambiguous; I would have assumed that you had to resolve the entire thing to meet "if you do."

Comment: @GendoIkari **CR117.12** Some spells, activated abilities, and triggered abilities read, “[Do something]. If [a player] [does or doesn’t], [effect].” or “[A player] may [do something]. If [that player] [does or doesn’t], [effect].” The action [do something] is a cost, paid when the spell or ability resolves. The “If [a player] [does or doesn’t]” clause checks whether the player chose to pay an optional cost or started to pay a mandatory cost, regardless of what events actually occurred.

Comment: @diego Thanks. But in this case, the ability is not optional, so does the "if you do" actually change anything in this case? Is there any situation in which you wouldn't get the Zombie token if the ability has triggered?

Comment: @GendoIkari This case would fall under the 'started to pay a mandatory cost' portion. You would not get a token if for example Lili's trigger was put on the stack and in response she is removed from the battlefield, since it is no longer possible to exile her.